# How to fetch several properties of a vertex in Gremlin?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

Say I have a vertex {first_name, last_name} in a graph database (Neo4j in this case).

I can get any of these properties by fetching them in a following way

```
g.v(1).first_name 
=> John
g.v(1).last_name 
=> Smith
```

I can get all properties by doing

```
g.v(1).map
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to fetch several properties at the same time (concatenate properties) eg

```
g.v(1).some-magic-here 
=> John Smith
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done using transform step

> **transform{closure}** emit the result of the closure

So, answering the question:

```
g.v(1).transform{it.first_name + ' ' + it.last_name}
=> John Smith
```